# Passing Parameters to yield in Rails 3 (or is it possible?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb, yield, content-for

I'm trying to create a dynamic content with `yield` and `content_for`. Basically i have bunch of layouts. And i dont want to create bunch of views for each layout. I want to render view parts when they are needed. For different parts of code it is ok. But i have problem with same parts with different content.

in my `application.html.erb`

```
<%= yield %>
<%= yield :name_section %>
```

And in my `show.html.erb` i have;

```
<% content_for :name_section do %>
    <b>Name:</b>
    <%= @post.name %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the question;

What if i want to multiple name_section with different contents. I mean; I want to put `:name_section` different places in my view with different contents.

For ex;

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= yield :name_section %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= yield :name_section %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.
Çağdaş

Comment: why do they need the same name?  Sure ruby does magic but it does read minds.

Comment: with different names i have to duplicate my code. but i think i solve this problem with helpers. thanks for response anyway.

Comment: don't forget not duplicating code and single responsibility are both important

Answer (score 9):

I believe that what you were asking for is now possible:

```
# The template
<%= render layout: "my_layout" do |customer| %>
  Hello <%= customer.name %>
<% end %>

# The layout
<html>
  <%= yield Struct.new(:name).new("David") %>
</html>
```

From:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-_layout_for

Hopefully this helps someone else looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Given the documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-_layout_for

and the source code of the method (you can browse it there):

```
def _layout_for(*args, &block)
  name = args.first

  if block && !name.is_a?(Symbol)
    capture(*args, &block)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

What you are asking for is not possible with `yield` in layout.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution has worked nicely for me.  It doesn't allow you to pass args, but if, right before calling `content_for` (the second time), you assign your args to instance variables, this allows you to reference your instance variables in `content_for`.  The basic idea is that `content_for` generates the content when it is called the 1st time and that content then remains static, but this workaround delays that static content generation until you're ready to display the content.

First, add this function to your helper module:

```
def immediate_content_for name, content = nil, &block
  @immediate_content ||= {}
  if content || block_given? then
    @immediate_content[name] = Proc.new { content_for name, content, &block }
    nil
  else
    @immediate_content[name].call
    content_for name
  end
end
```

Then, suppose you want to pass `arg1` to `content_for`.  You can now do this:

```
<% content_for :my_form %>
  <%= some_helper_function(@arg1) %>
<% end %>
```

Then, later in your code, after your defined `arg1`:

```
<%= @arg1 = arg1 %>
<%= content_for :my_form %>
```

It's a hack in the sense that I can't guarantee that the behavior of `immediate_content_for` is in all other way identical to that of `content_for`, and if the behavior of `content_for` changes in some future version of rails, you'll need to update `immediate_content_for` if you want it to continue mirroring `content_for`.  Although it's not an optimal solution, it does the job for now.